Is it acceptable for a physics student to write a master's thesis on quantum computing software?
I am a physics student, and I would like to write a master’s thesis in quantum computing programming, but my supervisor told me that in order for the master’s thesis to be accepted in the physics department, there must be a physics problem that you solve theoretically and then solve it using the cloud quantum computer, but according to my knowledge, the cloud quantum computer - Even the paid version cannot solve physics problems, but rather performs some mathematical operations, and there is no complete algorithm that can be used to solve physics problems.
Are there any suggestions for a master’s thesis title to convince my supervisor to accept the topic?

If I understand correctly, your question is whether there are quantum algorithms that are used (or can be used at least) to solve physics problem?

yes @TristanNemoz

There do exist quantum algorithms for solving physics and chemistry problems. So I wouldn't say outright that they "cannot solve physics problems". For example you can calculate ground state energies using the quantum phase estimation algorithm (for small molecules at present). However the quantum computing hardware we have today is not mature enough to run these algorithms at scale.
